# Using Japanese characters in DOMPDF?

Tags: dompdf

I'm trying to get my PDF's created using DOMpdf to work correctly with Japanese characters. I have it working fine with French etc, but Japanese characters don't show (just get ???)

Here is how the HTML page looks:

[image]

...but the PDF comes out as:

[image]

The code I'm using is pretty simple:

```
<?php

// include autoloader
require_once '/path/to/admin/invoices/autoload.inc.php';

define("DOMPDF_ENABLE_REMOTE", true);
define("DOMPDF_UNICODE_ENABLED", true);

// reference the Dompdf namespace
use Dompdf\Dompdf;

$order_id = $argv[1];

$content = file_get_contents("/path/to/admin/invoices/html_versions/$order_id.html");

// // instantiate and use the dompdf class
$dompdf = new Dompdf();
$dompdf->loadHtml($content);

 // Render the HTML as PDF
$dompdf->render();

// Output the generated PDF to Browser
$dompdf->stream();

?>
```

From what I can see, it wants a font specifically for Japanese.

1. What font would work?
2. Can I have it running alongside the normal font? i.e I still want to be able to show stuff like íóé etc

**UPDATE:** I'm getting a bit closer!

I've downloaded the CyberCJK TTF font (as suggested here: https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/issues/938 )

Then I tweaked my CSS to:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: CyberCJK;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    src: url("https://example.com/cgi-bin/admin/invoices/lib/fonts/DejaVuSerif.ttf") format("truetype");
}
* {
  font-family: 'CyberCJK', sans-serif;
}

@page { margin: 0px; } body { margin: 0px; }

html { font-size: 14px/1; font-family: 'CyberCJK', sans-serif; overflow: auto; }
```

..and now I get partial characters:

[image]

I have also tested uploading my HTML page on: http://www.htm2pdf.co.uk , and it comes out perfectly as a PDF, and is also only 64kb, compared to 13mb+ using DOMPdf. Something must be up!

I'm really at a loss as to what else to try :/

Comment: Do you have different styling applied to the characters coming out as question marks? As far as the size, make sure you have font subsetting enabled. Also, dompdf as of 0.7.0 no longer uses the configuration constants, try [`$dompdf->set_option()`](https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf#setting-options) instead.

Comment: I'm not too sure what you mean? The PHP script above is all I used (and then the HTML). I ended up giving up and using html2pdf.co.uk, as I didn't have the free time to waste trying to get this going :(

Comment: I guess it doesn't really matter since you found a different solution. But, what I meant was do you have a full sample of the HTML+CSS you're trying to render to PDF?